# Secure strategy for staying logged-in when using OpenID

Tags: authentication, cryptography, openid

I have a website that uses OpenID to sign in users. The library I'm using, returnes a user profile when the user logges in. This profile contains user's email, name, a link to the avatar and an **ID** which the OpenID provider has returned.

My strategy for keeping the user logged in is this:

- When the user logges in for the first time, I create a hash code based on the OpenID's returned ID
- I store this hash code alongside the user's ID in 2 cookies.
- When the user comes to my website, I check for these cookies, and if they're available, try to match the ID and the hash code, if it's correct, I log the user in.

Now the *problem* is this: if somehow this cookie information gets stolen from the user, the hacker can easily log in instead of the user himself. I could create a new hash code for each time the user logges in and update the user's cookeis but it'll make the information of other browsers/computers cookies invalid.

Since the StackOverflow website does not suffer from such problem, I would like to know what should I do to both secure my login strategy and add the functionality to stay signed in for the users.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hash code'? If it's simply a secure hash of the user's openid URL, an attacker can guess that - there's no need to go to the trouble of getting the original cookies in the first place.

Comment: How do you know that the StackOverflow website does not suffer from this problem?

Comment: @NickJohnson you're right, but I'm doing my best to make it difficult for them to guess. But somehow I think a random session id (as you mentioned) would be a better solution.

Comment: @zespri because when I log into two browsers, they both stay logged in.

Comment: And this indicates that if somehow your cookie information gets stolen from you, the hacker *can't* easily log in instead of you?

Comment: @zespri: You got me wrong. The *problem* that I mentioned was this part: "it'll make the information of other browsers/computers cookies invalid"

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to assign a meaningless session ID and send that as a cookie; in your database, you can store the user's credential information alongside that session ID. When a user logs out, you can invalidate that session ID.

Comment: Thank you. This is the easier AND the better solution I guess. (creating a **random** session ID, instead of creating it based on a hash algorithm + salt)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a problem with ALL mechanisms for letting the client stay logged in? If you log into your, say, gmail, and I steal your cookies, and put them in my own browser, there is no way to distinguish my browser from your browser and I get access to your gmail. There's no way to stop the kind of attack you're suggesting, I believe (other than the user keeping their computer free of viruses etc. that could steal the cookie)

Comment: So are you suggesting that this strategy (+ a way to renew the hash code for the users when their cookies has been stolen) is secure enough?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It prevents cookie forgery, which is good (i've implemented something similar for a project I'm working on). Nothing you can do about client browsers getting their credentials stolen, unless disabling auto-login if it's sensitive enough